# Sequence Word Problem Help

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

A camel is on his way to the University of Cairo to deliver a speech. The university is 200 miles away and the camel walks at 10 miles an hour, planning on walking all night and arriving the following morning. One hour into his journey the desert suddenly expands mysteriously by length of 200 miles.

From his GPS the camel can tell that the expansion with uniform across the desert so that the fraction of the desert which he has traversed has not changed. Still pretty weird, though. An hour later it happens again so the desert is now 600 miles across. On a proportional basis, however, he's still making progress just not as much as planned. Assume that the strange phenomenon contingencies but at the end of each hour the desert expense uniformly (like a giant rubber band) by 200 miles.

a) Find a sequence $x_n$ that gives a fraction of the desert crossed after $n$ hours.

b) Will the camel ever make it to the university? Explain your conclusion.

c) If he doesn't make it give an estimate of how long his journey will take. If he doesn't make it find an upper bound on $x_n$ that's less than 1.
$$\\$$

This is what I have so far:

After the first hour, the camel has crossed $\frac{1}{20}$ of the desert. After the second hour, $\frac{1}{40}$ more. So I got this as my sequence:

$$x_n = \frac{1}{20}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n}$$
$$\\$$

Since it's a harmonic series, I know it diverges.

I'm not quite so what to do next for part B & C.

Comment: c should say if he does make it estimate how long the journey will take.  If he doesn't make it, the journey lasts forever.

Comment: the camel is d e a d

Comment: @SakethMalyala, this is the strangest word problem I've ever come across

Comment: It seems a variaton of the crawling ant problem. Problem 76 here https://www.physics.harvard.edu/academics/undergrad/problems

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For part b) we know that since the series diverges, there exists an $n$ (th hour) that $x_n>1$, and the camel makes it all the  way to the University of Cairo.

For part c) He does make it. We need that $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{n}>20$.

Using an integral approximation gives us around $e^{20}$.

We can estimate $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^{t}\frac{1}{n}$ with $\displaystyle \int_{1}^{t}\frac{1}{n}\,dn=\ln(n)\bigg|_1^{t}=\ln(t)=20$ when $t=e^{20}$

We have that the difference of $\displaystyle \sum_{n=1}^x \frac{1}{n}$ and $\displaystyle \int_1^{x}\frac{1}{n}\,dn$ and  is $\gamma$, which is about $0.577$.

And almost ALL of that difference which sums up to $\gamma$, the (Euler Mascheroni Consant) is obtained within the first few terms.

Therefore, a more ACCURATE answer is $\displaystyle e^{20-\gamma}$.

[image]

Comment: Can you please elaborate on how you got $e^{20}$?

Comment: I haven't learned about Euler Mascheroni Consant

Comment: its just the limiting value of the difference between the sum and integral. if this is from a class, the teacher only expects $e^{20}$

Comment: Yes it's for class. So if it's $e^{20}$ does that mean it will take the camel 485165195.40 hours?

Comment: enough to die&fossilize @BBot

Comment: How did the limits go from [1,t] to [0,t] ?

Comment: typo sorry bro @BBot

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/61340/discussion-between-bbot-and-saketh-malyala).